# Applying Movmedian Within Cell Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, median

I have a cell array (2 x 6) called "output", each cell in row #1 {1 -> 6, 2} contains a 1024 x 1024 x 100 matrix. I want to apply movmedian to each cell in row #1. I would like to apply this function in dimension = 3 with window size = 5.

```
output = cellfun(@movmedian(5,3), output,'uniform', 0);
```

This is the code that I have come up with so far, however, it produces an "unbalenced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket" error. I am unsure what is causing this error. I am also somewhat unsure how to instruct matlab to perform this operation only on row 1 of the cell array, please help!

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) passed as the first argument to [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) will be sequentially  passed the contents of each cell (i.e. each 3-D matrix). Since you need to also pass the additional parameters needed by [`movmedian`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmedian.html), you should create an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like so:

```
@(m) movmedian(m, 5, 3)
```

Where the input argument `m` is the 3-D matrix. If you want to apply this to the first row of `output`, you just have to [index the cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#zmw57dd0e30160) like so:

```
output(1, :)
```

This will return a cell array containing the first row of `output`, with [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) indicating "all columns". You can use the same index in the assignment if you'd like to store the modified matrices back in the same cells of `output`.

Putting it all together, here's the solution:

```
output(1, :) = cellfun(@(m) movmedian(m, 5, 3), output(1, :),...
                       'UniformOutput', false);
```

...and a little trick to avoid having to specify `'UniformOutput', false` is to encapsulate the results of the anonymous function in a cell array:

```
output(1, :) = cellfun(@(m) {movmedian(m, 5, 3)}, output(1, :));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!

However, the entries in the cell don't seem to change after applying this bit of code... I was expecting them to become 1024 x 1024 x 19, but they stay 1024 x 1024 x 100. What do you think?

Comment: @itend: That's expected. `movmedian` uses a *sliding* window, so windows will overlap as opposed to the matrix being divided into distinct blocks. Check out the [additional arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmedian.html#namevaluepairarguments) for `movmedian`, which give you some options to change its behavior. You could also check out [distinct block processing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-distinct-block-operations.html) if you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: Ah, ok! I greatly appreciate the clarification.